# Hiding multiple datasets with a specific legend item

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have a chart with multiple legend items ( Lot Number, Median, and Range) and the Range legend item is not working as I want.   Range is SUPPOSED to consist of a upper control limit (UCL) and a lower control limit (LCL), and when clicked remove the range(UCL and LCL) from the chart just as the default onClick function operates. I have looked for ways to have multiple data sets under one legend item, but it seems it is not possible after research (tons of googling). So I am wondering if I should create a custom onClick function which manually hides the range (UCL and LCL). If I did write a custom function for the onClick event, can you specify which legend item is being clicked? I couldn't find any documentation. Because the trial function I wrote to just log a string takes away the default function of hiding the data when clicked.

```
I have these two data sets which work as intended seperated:
var LCL = 
      {label: 'LCL',
      label2: 'LCL',
      fill: false,
      pointRadius: 0,
      borderDash: [5,5],
      data: sum_LCL_data,
      backgroundColor: ['rgba(0,0,0,1)' ],
      borderColor: [ 'rgba(0,0,0,1)'],
      borderWidth: line_width[screenSec]};
var UCL = 
      {label: 'UCL',//only for label, really this is the UCL
      label2: 'UCL',
      fill: '-1',
      borderDash: [5,5],
      data: sum_UCL_data,
      backgroundColor:[ 'rgba(34, 139, 34, 0.2)' ],
      borderColor: ['rgba(0,0,0,1)' ],
      pointRadius: 0,
      borderWidth: line_width[screenSec]};
```

It is when I attempt to combine them in variable Range that the problems start:

```
var Range = 
      {label: 'Range', 
      label2: 'Range', 
      data:[UCL, LCL],
      fill: false,
      borderDash: [5,5],
      data: sum_UCL_data,
      backgroundColor:[ 'rgba(34, 139, 34, 0.2)' ],
      borderColor: ['rgba(0,0,0,1)' ],
      pointRadius: 0,
      borderWidth: line_width[screenSec]};
```

This shows nothing on the graph but creates the legend item.

What I am wanting it to do is hide the two data (UCL and LCL) sets if I click on Range legend item.

Comment: you can try filtering the dataset

Comment: I have looked into filters but I do not want to add another button on my GUI. It would be much easier if there was a way to have a function that work if only the Range data legend item is toggled